# Упрощение sql запроса

Tags: php, mysql

Упростите (сократите) данный код.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM `pages`");
$r = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
$name = $r['name'];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$name = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT name FROM `pages`"))['name'];
```

ыыыы =)

Comment: имеет смысл, а почему нет? (это к Deonis'у)

Comment: @Viczech, а чем же это хорошо? Вам могут подать все блюда поотдельности, а можно в одной тарелке смешать солянку, салат оливье, туда же шашлычки закинуть и приправить компотом. Ну, а почему бы и нет? Ведь в желудке все равно перемешается.

P.S. @Gorets, по рукам бы дал за то, что маленьких плохому учишь ))

Comment: @Deonis, да мне самому стыдно. Уважаемые господа начинающие программисты, никогда-никогда не пишите так как я вам показал, это образец того - как делать не надо.

Answer (score 0):

Пишите свой класс для работы с бд, там делайте функцию, которая будет выбирать указанное поле в качестве параметра. Будет вам код в одну строку.

Answer (score 0):

```
$name=mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT name FROM `pages`"),0,'name');
```